# Symfony Translation using YAML files

Tags: symfony

I'm currently facing a problem with translations in symfony2.

Some translations are loading, some not.

My *messages.de.yml*:

```
form:
    label:
        save: Speichern
status:
    daten_mangelhaft: Die Daten scheinen etwas mager zu sein, bitte überprüfen.
```

Some twig file:

```
{{ 'form.label.save'|trans }}
```

outputs (as expected):

```
Speichern
```

whereas (same twig file):

```
{{ 'status.daten_mangelhaft'|trans }}
```

outputs:

```
status.daten_mangelhaft
```

If I add it into the messages.de.yml as follows it works:

```
status.daten_mangelhaft: Die Daten scheinen etwas mager zu sein, bitte überprüfen.
```

I really don't get it, it works in some cases but not in others.

I tried:

- Clearing Cache
- omitting special chars (ä, ö, ü) in translations
- omitting under score in identifier
- Wrapping translations in quotes or single quotes

to no avail.

Has anyone ever had this problem before? How did you solve it?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the translation string with `"` or `'`?

Comment: Yeah I have (I'll update the question). It doesn't help.

Comment: Try to set traslation domain. Translation domain is the name of file with translation so try

     {{ 'status.daten_mangelhaft'|trans({},'messages') }}

Comment: That did not work either, and honestly I didn't expect it to because other translations from the same file are shown on the same page. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: I still haven't solved this problem FYI, I use a yaml to xliff converter and that works.

Comment: Any news about that ? I have the same problem on my project. Some translations works fine and a few needs to be "inline" to work...

Comment: Nothing new sorry

Answer (score 0):

Is this still accurate?

However: did you check your fallback language in your config.yml?

```
framework:
    translator: {fallbacks: ['de']}
    default_locale: 'de'
```

You can also use the locale parameter from your parameters.yml file and have:

```
framework:
    translator: {fallbacks: ['%locale%']}
    default_locale: '%locale%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running `php app/console translation:update` after having deleted your translations (makesure you saved them). It should make a list of your needed translations.
With that you would be sure of where and what to write.